# Can we find out which statement in an IF statement with multiple ORs was being passed?

Tags: php, if-statement, return

If we have an if-statement such as

```
`<?php if($data[1][0][1] == "aaa" || $data[2][0][1] == "bbb" || $data[1][0][2] == "ccc" || $data[2][0][2] == "ddd")
{
  $return_value = {the index array value being passed above};
  echo "which portion in the if statement OR was actually passed? and return that value" . $return_value;
}?>`
```

can we find out exactly which actually value was being passed in the OR if-statement?

Comment: Your first part of the expression is invalid, it should be `$data[1][0][1]`. And, no. Without breaking up the IF, there's no way to signify which part of the expression was true.

Comment: thanks!, just wanted to verify on that thought

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your if-statement, we can not find out which part is true.

Here is something more detail about [Short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

Answer (score 1):

The only way in my opinion is by removing all the OR conditions leaving one of them.
OR
you can try this one

```
`<?php if($data[1][0][1] == "aaa")
{
  echo 'first If';
}
if($data[2][0][1] == "bbb"){
  echo 'second if';
}
if($data[1][0][2] == "ccc"){ echo 'third if';}

if($data[2][0][2] == "ddd"){
echo 'fourth if';
}
?>`
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the fact that the assign will return a value

So

```
if (($part = 1 && $data[1][0][1] = "aaa") ||
```

Etc. Then check part in the if statement. It will be set to the part which triggered the true statement

Though if it would probably be better to take it out of the if statement and have a better structure for it